# UTF-8 byte[] to String

Tags: java, utf-8

Let's suppose I have just used a `BufferedInputStream` to read the bytes of a UTF-8 encoded text file into a byte array. I know that I can use the following routine to convert the bytes to a string, but is there a more efficient/smarter way of doing this than just iterating through the bytes and converting each one?

```
public String openFileToString(byte[] _bytes)
{
    String file_string = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < _bytes.length; i++)
    {
        file_string += (char)_bytes[i];
    }

    return file_string;    
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just do this  `String fileString = new String(_bytes,"UTF-8");` ?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use BufferedReader to read into a char array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I read/convert an InputStream to a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Comment: @CoolBeans I could if I had known to do that ;) Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the file size, I'm not sure loading the whole `byte[]` in memory and converting it via `new String(_bytes,"UTF-8")` (or even by chunks with `+=` on the string) is the most efficient. Chaining InputStreams and Readers might work better, especially on large files.

Comment: @Bruno - That's a valid observation. I guess he will find out if he starts getting out of memory exceptions :)

Comment: Your provided cide does **not** decode UTF-8. It does not handle *any* of the code points that require  multiple bytes.

Answer (score 547, accepted):

Look at the constructor for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And if you're feeling lazy, you can use the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library to convert the InputStream to a String directly:

```
String str = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Or Guava's [Charsets.UTF_8](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Charsets) if you are on JDK older than 1.7

Comment: Use Guava's Charsets.UTF_8 if you are on Android API below 19 too

Comment: And if checkstyle says: "Illegal Instantiation: Instantiation of java.lang.String should be avoided.", then what?

Comment: You can see in here the `java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets()` map all the charsets not just the charsets in the `StandardCharsets`. And if you want to use some other charset and still want to prevent the String constructor from throwing `UnsupportedEncodingException` you may use `java.nio.charset.Charset.forName()`

Comment: IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) is deprecated now.

Comment: This will crash on large data with out-of-memory on a TC75 Zebra device.

Comment: It worked for me without specifying `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. I just did `new String(bytes)`

Comment: `Constructs a new {@code String} by decoding the specified array of` says in java source doc, wondering, if there are bytes can not be decoded in specified Charset, lets say UTF-8, then what will happen.

Answer (score 43):

Java String class has a built-in-constructor for converting byte array to string.

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};

String value = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 12):

To convert utf-8 data, you can't assume a 1-1 correspondence between bytes and characters.
Try this:

```
String file_string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

(Bah. I see I'm way to slow in hitting the Post Your Answer button.)

To read an entire file as a String, do something like this:

```
public String openFileToString(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

    try {
        InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        char[] buff = new char[4096];
        int len = rdr.read(buff);
        while (len >= 0) {
            contents.append(buff, 0, len);
        }
        return buff.toString();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log error in closing the file
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `String(byte[] bytes)`  constructor for that. See this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) for details.
**EDIT** You also have to consider your plateform's default charset as per the java doc:

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
>   the platform's default charset. The length of the new String is a
>   function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of
>   the byte array. The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes
>   are not valid in the default charset is unspecified. The
>   CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the
>   decoding process is required.

Comment: And if your bytes are not in the platform's default charset, you can use the version that has the second `Charset` argument to make sure the conversion is correct.

Comment: @MikeDaniels Indeed, I did not want to include all the details. Just edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that you are dealing with a UTF-8 byte array, you'll definitely want to use the [String constructor that accepts a charset name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29). Otherwise you may leave yourself open to some charset encoding based security vulnerabilities. Note that it throws [`UnsupportedEncodingException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/UnsupportedEncodingException.html) which you'll have to handle. Something like this:

```
public String openFileToString(String fileName) {
    String file_string;
    try {
        file_string = new String(_bytes, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // this should never happen because "UTF-8" is hard-coded.
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return file_string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the methods described in this question (especially since you start off with an InputStream): [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/372643)

In particular, if you don't want to rely on external libraries, you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309718/372643), which reads the `InputStream` via an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) into a `char[]` buffer and appends it into a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified function that will read in bytes and create a string. It assumes you probably already know what encoding the file is in (and otherwise defaults).

```
static final int BUFF_SIZE = 2048;
static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "utf-8";

public static String readFileToString(String filePath, String encoding) throws IOException {

    if (encoding == null || encoding.length() == 0)
        encoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING;

    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];

    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
        content.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, encoding));

    fis.close();        
    return content.toString();
}
```

Comment: Code edited to make the default be utf-8 to match the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

String has a constructor that takes byte[] and charsetname as parameters :)

Answer (score 0):

This also involves iterating, but this is much better than concatenating strings as they are very very costly.

```
public String openFileToString(String fileName)
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(_bytes.length);

    for(int i = 0; i < _bytes.length; i++)
    {
        s.append((char)_bytes[i]);
    }

    return s.toString();    
}
```

Comment: my dear lord. `String str = new String(byte[])` will do just fine.

Comment: This improves the efficiency, but it doesn't decode utf8 data properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get what you are looking for from the get go and read a string from the file instead of an array of bytes?  Something like:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( "foo.txt"), Charset.forName( "UTF-8"));
```

then readLine from in until it's done.

Comment: Sometimes, it's useful to keep the original line delimiters. The OP might want that.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way

`String strIn = new String(_bytes, 0, numBytes);`

Comment: This doesn't specify a character set so you get the platform default character set which may well not be UTF-8.