# Sending ByteArray from PHP to Java

Tags: java, php, post, aes, url-encoding

I have problems with sending AES encrypted data from JAVA to PHP.

My encrypt function:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String input, String key, String iv) {

    byte[] raw = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8"));
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_MODE);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes()));
        return cipher.doFinal(padString(input).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return new byte[0];
}
```

encrypt function is returning data in byte array
To send POST data, I'm using apache HttpClient/HttpPost (preferred, but not necessary)

```
    HttpEntity params = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .addTextBody("data1", new String(encodedData1, Charset.forName("UTF8")))
            .addTextBody("data2", new String((encodedData2, Charset.forName("UTF8")))
            .addTextBody("data3", "data3").build();
```

Now, I recieve data with PHP server (i can't add functionality here)

```
        $data1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data1');
        $data2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data2');
        $data1decoded = DecryptAES($data1, $key, $iv);
        $data2decoded = DecryptAES($data2, $key, $iv);
```

What is a proper way to send encoded byte[] from JAVA to PHP? I know, that Base64.encode would be probably best option, but unfortunately (as I have mentioned earlier) I can't modify PHP server-side code... new String(encodedData1, Charset.forName("UTF8")) is not working.

In node.js I can use toString('binary') to send data in proper format.

Comment: Do mix text with binary or you will get corruption. Also it is not clear to me what language you are using.  Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Java. I need to rewrite old library to Java... And client receiving data is written in PHP.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to convert at all, please post relevant PHP code, otherwise this question cannot be answered (at least not by me, and I presume by anybody else that lacks a crystal ball).

Comment: I have updated my original question

Comment: @owlstead Is there a way to send binary data to php in one array with normal string?

Comment: Normally base 64 encoding is used for that.

Comment: HTTP POST allows for binary data, MIME as well, so you could try and use [this method](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html#addBinaryBody(java.lang.String,%20byte[])) to add binary content. So don't convert all the way back to `HttpEntity`.

Comment: @owlstead I've tried with MultipartEntityBuilder#addBinaryBody, but it's content goes to PHP $_FILES array. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are missing, obviously I'm missing what is performed in `DecryptAES`.

Comment: @owlstead DecryptAES is Crypt_AES() from  http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net

Comment: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Crypt/AES.php

Comment: Have you tried just converting any bytes to a string directly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512121/byte-to-string-java - the question here has a simple way of doing it, that's different than what you're trying.

Comment: Why are you returning return new byte[0];? shouldn't it be return raw ?

Comment: @dAngelov Yes. I have tried few ways of converting byte[] to String. Unfortunately they are not good for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't just create new `String` (Java is too fancy for that).**

Use

```
public static String byteToString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte c : bytes) {
        b.append((char) (c >= 0 ? c : 256 + c));
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Using your example

```
HttpEntity params = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
          .addTextBody("data", byteToString(data))
          .build();
```

Comment: Sending string like this gave me error 500 from apache. Have you tried it with success?

Comment: Yeap. I tested it on php-fpm+nginx. What error_log says?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
new String(encodedData1, Charset.forName("UTF8"))
```

you should use

```
new String(encodedData1)
```

Comment: I've also tried without encoding. Without success :(

Answer (score 0):

Your byte array doesn't contain an UTF8 text anymore once it has been encrypted. You would preserve the exact structure of your byte aray by sending it in its original form with the addBinaryBody method instead of casting it to a String in order to use the addTextBody method.