# How to check File Integrity using md5 over camel route to S3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel, md5

I am sending a file to s3 bucket using camel. I want to verify the file integrity using md5. i am using `org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils`.

```
from(ftp_endpoint)
    .idempotentConsumer(simple("${in.header.CamelFileName}"), redisIdempotentRepository)
    .setHeader(S3Constants.KEY, simple("${file:name}"))
    .setHeader(S3Constants.CONTENT_MD5, simple(DigestUtils.md5(body().toString()).toString()))
    .to(s3_endpoint)
```

I am getting the following exception

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid. 
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDigest; Request ID: 8462458C6250091C)
```

How do i calculate the MD5 correctly so that it uploads to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
from(ftp_endpoint)
    .idempotentConsumer(simple("${in.header.CamelFileName}"), redisIdempotentRepository)
    .setHeader(S3Constants.KEY, simple("${file:name}"))
    .process(md5HeadersProcessor)
    .to(s3_endpoint)


public class Md5HeadersProcessor implements Processor {
    private java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder = java.util.Base64.getEncoder();

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] bytes = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(bytes);
        String md5= encoder.encodeToString(md.digest());
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(S3Constants.CONTENT_MD5, md5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can spot a couple of issues in your setHeader.

```
.setHeader(S3Constants.CONTENT_MD5, simple(DigestUtils.md5(body().toString()).toString()))
```

First, you are NOT calculating MD5 of your body (which I assume it's `byte[]` since you're reading a file) because you are calling `toString()` on it.
Second, docs for [DigestUtils.md5](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5(byte[])) states that the return type is `byte[]` which once again you are calling `toString()` on it.

Calling `toString()` on a byte array returns a String containing something like

> [B@106d69c

See for example [this other question on SO "UTF-8 byte[] to String"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8512121/423955).

You can try this solution using [DigestUtils.md5Hex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5Hex(byte[])) which returns the hash as a String:

```
.setHeader(S3Constants.CONTENT_MD5, simple(DigestUtils.md5Hex(body())))
```