# Sending Arduino ADC Data to Android Tablet via USB Serial

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I'm trying to send Arduino ADC data to android tablet using USB serial Communication. I'm using `Serial.println()` at arduino side. My Issue is that I'm not able to Decode the data received at the android end.
For Eg. Suppose I send `Serial.println(768)` from arduino, I check my android receive buffer and it Shows **(55,54,56,13,10)**.

How can i decode this data back to **768** value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert byte array to string and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you'll find that

```
55,54,56,13,10
```

represents

```
"768\n\r"
```

Most programming languages provide means for conversion between byte values and characters/strings with their string libraries. So you don't have to implement the decoding yourself.

Refer to https://howtodoinjava.com/array/convert-byte-array-string-vice-versa/

or [UTF-8 byte[] to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512121/utf-8-byte-to-string)

or anything else you find online for "byte to string Android"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The link you provided does help me solving my issue. I had already figured out the decoding part after posting my question.Actually the .getbytes method also puts new CR & LN in the string but I wanted to omit those bytes and only interested in number part

Answer (score 0):

String rawdata = " " ;
String finaldata = " ";
UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {

```
        byte[] buffer = arg0;
        for (i =0;i <=(buffer.length-1);i++) {
         if(buffer[i]!= 13) {
             if(buffer[i]== 10){
                 finaldata = rawdata;
                 rawdata = "";
             }else {
                 chdata = (char) buffer[i];
                 rawdata += chdata;
             }
         }

      }

            data = Integer.parseInt(finaldata);
```

}